# How can I tell how many minutes have passed between Now() and 7am that day?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Basically I just need to know how much time has passed from a certain time that day till Now() this will be run on a timer throughout the day and used to determine when something should be run (this might seem odd but there is logic behind it).

The issue with the code below is that it gives me a very high negative number.  I can only assume that this is caused from the TimeSerial not actually containing a date and only the time so it throws everything off.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a way to do what I want?  I am certain that the answer is something super simple that I am missing but I haven't been able to find it.

```
DateDiff("n",Now(),TimeSerial(07,0,0))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the number of minutes from 7 AM until now.  Your `DateDiff` had those two swapped around and that's why you got a negative value.

The reason the magnitude of that number was so large is you were asking for the difference between 07:00 on Dec 30 1899 and today.  This is what that `TimeSerial` expression gives you ...

```vb
? Format(TimeSerial(07,0,0), "mmm d yyyy, hh:nn:ss")
Dec 30 1899, 07:00:00
```

I think this is what you want instead ...

```vb
DateDiff("n", Date + #07:00#, Now)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, the "Date + #07:00#" is interesting.  I don't work frequently with dates so the nature of that statement definitely helps me understand how dates are handled.

Comment: In that case, I'll suggest you go to the Immediate window and check out what `CDbl(Date)`, `CDbl(#07:00#)`, and `CDbl(Now)` show you.  Also look at `Format(0, "mmm d yyyy, hh:nn:ss")`.  Have fun!  :-)

Comment: That is super neat, so basically it can be broken down to nothing but a number.  Each whole number representing a day, and the time of that day represented by a decimal. Basically counting up from 1899 December 30th.  Which makes sense how you can simply say 2015-01-15 + #07:00# because that translates to 42019 + 0.2196.  Thanks Hans that gives me a much better understanding of dates.